# My users claim that suddenly my app assumes another user

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's the problem I'm facing and I can't  figure out the issue nor debug, since it does not happen to me:

My users claim that sometimes after they logged in, while navigating through the app, their loggin session is switched to another user.
They notice this because the name in the navigation bar is switched, for example.

I'm using CodeIgniter as a framework and I have not encounter this problem in other apps. Notice: the app is in a subdomain (somename.mydomain.com)

My tables (with the fields that matter):

```
Users -> id, email, session_id
Users_auth -> id, user_id, selector, token, session_id, active, date_expire
```

The logic behind the validation to check if the user is logged in while navigating through the pages.

```
public function isUserLoggedIn()
{
    // If the session exists, the user is logged in
    if($this->CI->session->userdata('user') != null)
        return TRUE;

    // The cookie must exists
    if(get_cookie('data', TRUE) == null)
         return FALSE;

    $cookie                 = get_cookie('data', TRUE);
    list($selector, $token) = explode('::', $cookie); 

    if($selector == null || $token == null)
        return FALSE;

    // The token in the cookie is not encrypted, but it is on the database
    $token          = hash('sha256', $token);
    $listOfAuths    = $this->CI->usersauth_model->getAll($selector); // Ordered by id DESC

    // If no selector is found then the auth does not exists or is no longer active
    if(count($listOfAuths) <= 0)
        return FALSE;

    $is_auth_valid  = TRUE;
    $auth_index     = 0;

    foreach($listOfAuths as $key => $auth)
    {
        if(hash_equals($auth->token, $token) == FALSE)
        {
            $is_auth_valid = FALSE;
            break;
        }

        // Validates the date expire of the auth
        if(strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($auth->date_expire))) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
        {
            $is_auth_valid = FALSE;
            break;
        }

        $auth_index = $key;
        break;
    }

    if($is_auth_valid == FALSE)
        return FALSE;

    // Gets the correct index from the authentication
    $lastAuth = $listOfAuths[$auth_index];

   /*
    * If the code reaches here it means:
    *   1. The cookie is well set (selector::token)
    *   2. The values from cookie (selector and token) are correct
    *   3. The authentication is not experied yet
    */         
    $user = $this->CI->users_model->get($lastAuth->user_id);

    if($user == null || $user->active == FALSE)
        return FALSE;

    /*
     * It is only allowed the user to be loggedIn in one place, therefore 
     * the current session id must be equal to the last session id set on the UsersAuth table.
     */
    if($lastAuth->session_id != $user->session_id)
        return FALSE;

    $this->auth($user);

    return TRUE;
}
```

And the logic to apply after the user is validated successfully (by setting the cookie, add to database, etc):

```
public function auth($user)
{
    $selector       = $this->utils->random(12);
    $token          = $this->utils->random(64);
    $token_hash     = hash('sha256', $token);

    $this->CI->session->set_userdata(array
    (
        'user' => array
        (
            'id'      => $user->id,
            'name'    => $user->name,
            'email'   => $user->email
        )
    ));

    $cookie = array
    (
        'name'      => 'data',
        'value'     => $selector . '::' . $token,
        'expire'    => 3600 * 24 * 30 * 6
    );

    set_cookie($cookie);

    $auth_history['user_id']        = $user->id;
    $auth_history['active']         = TRUE;
    $auth_history['date_expire']    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month'));       
    $auth_history['selector']       = $selector;
    $auth_history['token']          = $token_hash;
    $auth_history['session_id']     = $this->CI->session->session_id;

    /*
     * 1. Sets all auths in the database inactive for the user 
     * 2. Add's one auth that's the only one active 
     * 3. Updates the user table is the last session_id
     */
    $this->CI->usersauth_model->setAllAuthsInactive($user->id);
    $this->CI->usersauth_model->add($auth_history);
    $this->CI->users_model->edit($user->id, array('session_id' => $auth_history['session_id']));
}
```

`$this->CI` is an instance of CodeIgniter.

Can anyone see any issue that would lead to the fact that the session could switch between users?

The only thing it occurred to me was the fact that the `selector` could potentially be duplicated in the database, but the token wouldn't match the selector and therefore the function would retrieve `FALSE`.

Nevertheless I checked the database and there is no duplicated values.

Answer (score 3):

`$this->utils->random()` doesn't create a unique number. It creates a random number. Since you're only passing the first argument, selector is a random number between 0 and 12, and token is a random number between 0 and 64. That's less than a thousand combinations.

If you want a unique number, you should use one of the many ways to generate secure random number. I'm no expert, but I think `random_int()`, `random_bytes`(), or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` should at the very least be more suitable. [Here's a good article for further reading](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php) per  DFriend in the comments below

Additionally, I think you're doing too much here, if you just want simple user sessions at least. I usually just set the session with the session library. I've never manually handled the cookies or recorded sessions or cookies in the db.

Comment: `uniqid`, despite its name, does not really produce guaranteed unique values either. If you want a practically guaranteed unique random value, use UUIDs.

Comment: Here's a very good article on [How to Securely Generate Random Strings and Integers in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php)

Comment: @deceze That is right. I'll edit my question. At the very least for what it's worth, uniqid is much better than what OP is using.